# Concurrent Static Queue in C# not keeping my data

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, concurrency, static

So I have data that is processed in one thread and put into a queue, then another thread is dequeing the information and performing some actions on it.

Here is the queue

```
public static class MyConcurrentQueue
{
    public static ConcurrentQueue<cRule> _Queue;

    public static void EnqueueRuleTrigger(cRule _Rule)
    {
        MyConcurrentQueue._Queue.Enqueue(_Rule);
    }
}
```

on application_start i have

```
 MyConcurrentQueue._Queue = new ConcurrentQueue<cRule>();
```

if i want to enqueue a rule i use

```
MyConcurrentQueue.EnqueueRuleTrigger(_Rule); //We're done enqueue the rule
```

to dequeue I use

```
 MyConcurrentQueue._Queue.TryDequeue(out _Rule)
```

I noticed that if enqueued 2 items, 1 after the other in a tight loop that by the time of the first dequeue [separate asynch thread], the data in the log file didn't match the enqueue anymore

If I put a sleep between the enqueues the log reads the correct values, probably because one item is put in, dequeued, another item put in, dequeued.

I suppose this is because the queue is static and it is storing a reference to _Rule instead of a copy of it.  Any ideas on how I can fix this?  I need the queue to be accessible to multiple threads that's why I made it static in the first place.

Thanks in advance.

*EDIT*

Here is my enqueue and log and dequeue and log logic

```
while (x<=y)
                    {

  MyConcurrentQueue.EnqueueRuleTrigger(_Rule); //We're done enqueue the string AllText = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Default\New.txt");
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Default\New.txt", AllText + "\r\nEnqueue Alert:" +
 _Rule.AlertID +":" + _Rule.TriggerStartTime + "-" + _Rule.TriggerEndTime);

}
```

This is on a separate thread

```
if ( MyConcurrentQueue._Queue.TryDequeue(out _Rule))
                {
... some logic
     File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Default\New.txt", AllText + "\r\nDequeue Alert:" + 
_Rule.AlertID + ":" + _Rule.TriggerStartTime + "-" + _Rule.TriggerEndTime);
    }
```

this is my log file

Enqueue Alert:64c88289-58a1-499b-ade9-3fa69a32cf47: 4/27/2012 12:00:00 PM-4/27/2012 5:00:00 PM

Enqueue Alert:64c88289-58a1-499b-ade9-3fa69a32cf47: 4/28/2012 2:00:00 PM-4/28/2012 9:00:00 PM

Dequeue Alert:64c88289-58a1-499b-ade9-3fa69a32cf47: 4/28/2012 2:00:00 PM-4/28/2012 9:00:00 PM

Dequeue Alert:64c88289-58a1-499b-ade9-3fa69a32cf47: 4/28/2012 2:00:00 PM-4/28/2012 9:00:00 PM

Comment: So far nothing particularly wrong with code, but it is not very clear what is failing. Side note: please consider to follow C# coding guidelines when posting sample code, i.e. not name classes starting with lowercase letter (cRule).

Comment: I'll check out the coding guidelines thanks :)

Sorry, I have a log file that makes an entry when i enqueue, and when i dequeue.
If I have 2 items, say A and B.  
A.value = 1
B.value = 2.
I will have a log file that looks like
enqueue value 1
Dequeue value 2
enqueue Value 2
Dequeue Value 2
Consider I enqueue A and B in a loop on one thread and dequeue them in another thread asynch.  Seems the problem is the 2nd enqueue in  a tight loop overwrites the value of the first enqueue. If I put a sleep in between enqueues the logs read the proper values.

Comment: This leads me to believe ultimately that I am having some sort of reference issue.  Hence i enqueue once and dequeue once the value in the log is correct [because I put the sleep in there to ensure the 2nd enqueue doesn't happen before the log writes].  
Without the sleep essentially the first dequeue of the first object has the values for the 2nd object [as does the 2nd object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Seems to be an issue with enqueing an object, than changing the same object and enqueing it second time. As result during dequeue it looks like second object overrode the first and was inserted twice, in reality reference to the same object was inserted twice.

Most likely solution is to deep clone before insert. Consider making your objects immutable to simplify synchronization and readability of the code.

Original:

Most likly reason is your logging code is not properly synchronized. Since it looks like you want 2 action to happen atomically (Enqueue + Log or Dequeue+Log) you have to add proper locking around both operations, otherwise order of calls to Queue and Log may be semi-random. Also make sure you correctly handle result of TryDequeue (since it can return false).

```
static object logAndQueueLock = new object();
public static void EnqueueRuleTrigger(Rule rule) 
{ 
    lock(logAndQueueLock)
    {
      MyConcurrentQueue._Queue.Enqueue(rule); 
      Log.Message("Enqueued:"+ rule.ToString());
    } 
} 

public static Rule DequeueRuleTrigger() 
{ 
    lock(logAndQueueLock)
    {
      Rule rule = null;
      if (MyConcurrentQueue._Queue.Enqueue(out rule)){ 
         Log.Message("Enqueued:"+ rule.ToString());
      }
      return rule; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please see my updated code.  I suspect that is not the case [Although I could certainly be wrong] as I put the logging operation right after the enqueue and right after the dequeue and you will see the data that i am getting out is not correct.  However if I add a sleep between the two enqueues I get the proper data, in my log.  My suspicion is that by the time the first dequeue happens the 2nd enqueue has already happened [It's in a tight loop] and _Rule is being treated like a reference or something instead of a copied vale and so they are all sharing 1 reference.  Thanks

Comment: I assume you **are not** using some sort of shared member variable in call to TryDeque (see my Dequeue call). Otherwise you need proper locking around it too. Note that your tracing may result in arbitrary order of entries...

Comment: I should posted that portion sorry
`Rule _Rule = new Rule();
            if ( MyConcurrentQueue._Queue.TryDequeue(out _Rule))`
each time that thread is called it should be creating a brand new rule.

Comment: Are you sure that your "some logic" code does not touch _Rule local variable? (Note: no point to create new rule right before Dequeue. )

Comment: Furthermore if you notice I am getting 2 different things enqueued and the same thing dequeued twice.  So it isn't an order thing it is actually changing the reference in the queue somehow.

Comment: I changed it to not make a new rule, good observation :)
The "some logic" I just looked at again, it's not modifying the _Rule, it is creating a dictionary and using it to seed a stored procedure to log the values in the database [which has the same results as the log file] It is only reading from the _Rule

Comment: How many objects are created in your Enqueu code? Is it something likle Rule r= new Rule(); Enque(r); r.Name = "another"; Enqueue(r)? Are you sure you enqueue different **objects**, not the same object with different **properties**? This would explain why you are getting properties of second one on both calls to dequeu (as there just 2 references to the same object).

Comment: I put the code up, it is going through a loop and doing the enqueing so I don't know how many it will do for any given thing, in this case it is triggering twice in this method.
I think you are probably correct though I am unsure of what I am doing wrong.... it's probably a case of 1:45am and it's escaping me :)

Comment: I suppose I need to do a deep clone of _Rule into __Rule ?

Comment: Yes, deep clone will solve the issue, but it may not be what you want for your program - you decide.

Comment: Thanks, I wouldn't have come to the conclusion without your help.

Comment: If I queue off an object in a producer thread, I immediately new() another one in the very next line, so overwriting the pointer and preventing any further access to the 'old' pointer.  The producer and consumer are then always operating on different object instances.  yes, this can mean repeated initialization of some fields in the new objects, but it's safer, and probably quicker, than copying the objects.